# Inno Setup define a hexadecimal color constant

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to use the `[ISPP]` section to define a hexadecimal color which will later be used in the `[Code]` section as a spot color, the value of which may change in the future, but I am getting a type mismatch error when running. Here are the relevant sections from the code:

```
[ISPP]
#define ColorPetrol "$C8C264"

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  PortLabel: TNewStaticText;
begin
  PortLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  PortLabel.Caption := 'Port';
  PortLabel.Top := ScaleY(78);
  PortLabel.Parent := Page.Surface;
  PortLabel.Font.Color := ExpandConstant('{#ColorPetrol}');
end;
```

I am assuming the error is caused by the define constant being a string and the `PortLabel.Font.Color` requiring a hex value. How can the constant be defined in the `[ISPP]` section and used in this way correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `PortLabel.Font.Color := {#ColorPetrol};`. `ExpandConstant()` is for expanding built-in Inno Setup constants, not for ISPP defines. The latter really are just about textual replacements.

As a side note, I'm not aware of an `[ISPP]` section. IMO you should just move the define to the `[Code]` section.

Comment: That's right. That `ExpandConstant` call would after preprocessing expand the string `'$C8C264'`. But it doesn't matter where you define the variables (or macros). The only rule is that it (whatever it is) must be defined before it's used because preprocessing goes from top to the bottom of the file. And that `[ISPP]` will be some virtual section of a tool like Inno Script Studio, I guess. One tip, if you add line like `#expr SaveToFile('C:\PreprocessedScript.iss')` to the very end of the script, the whole preprocessed script will be saved into a file where you will see how it was processed.